# MySQL Stored Procedure Beginner Error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm learning about MySQL stored procedures but I'm a bit stumped with a procedure I'm trying to create.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE tag_inserts
(
IN myTag VARCHAR(255), 
IN profileID INT(11)
)

BEGIN

INSERT IGNORE INTO tags(tag) VALUES(myTag);

SET @lid = LAST_INSERT_ID();

 IF(@lid = 0,
 (SELECT tagid FROM tags WHERE tag = myTag),
 (INSERT INTO profile_hashtags (pid,tagid) VALUES (profileID,@lid)));

END
```

When I execute it, it's giving me the following error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO profile_hashtags (pid,tagid) VALUES (profileID,@lid))); 
>   END' at line 13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`if()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function you've used is meant for conditional evaluation of an expression. What you want is the procedural-flow-control [`IF` compound statement syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html), which would look like this:

```
-- Some client apps require DELIMITER directives, and some don't.
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE tag_inserts (IN myTag VARCHAR(255), IN profileID INT(11))
  BEGIN
    INSERT IGNORE INTO tags (tag)
      VALUES (myTag);
    SET @lid = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    IF @lid = 0 THEN
      SELECT tagid
        INTO @lid
        FROM tags
        WHERE tag = myTag;
      INSERT INTO profile_hashtags
          (pid, tagid)
        VALUES
          (profileID, @lid);
    END IF;
  END;

-- Some client apps require DELIMITER directives, and some don't.
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Note also the `SELECT ... INTO` syntax used to retrieve selected values into procedural variables.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation Darwin.  Here's the new output. SQL query:

CREATE PROCEDURE tag_inserts( IN myTag VARCHAR( 255 ) , IN profileID INT( 11 ) ) BEGIN INSERT IGNORE INTO tags( tag ) 
VALUES (

'myTag'
);

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: What client are you using? Workbench, `mysql`, phpMyAdmin...?

Comment: Some MySQL clients, notably `mysql` and MySQL Workbench, require that you use [`DELIMITER` directives](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html) when entering compound statements. I've added them to my solution above.

Comment: Darwin, Yup, that was it, I usually use toad for MySQL, but for some reason was trying to do it directly inside phpMyAdmin and when I added the delimiter everything worked fine.  Thanks for the help. I will go ahead and jump and start reading up more on MySQL Stored Procedures :)